LAB to LCH colour conversion
I'm trying to convert CIE Lab colours to CIE LCH based on Easy RGB and lab-lch.js
Here's what I'm using
function LAB_to_LCH(LAB)
{
    var labL = LAB[0];
    var labA = LAB[1];
    var labB = LAB[2];

    // https://easyrgb.com/en/math.php
    var lchH = Math.atan( labB, labA );
    // alert("lch (radians): " + lchH)
    lchH = to_degrees(lchH);

    lchL = labL;
    lchC = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(labA,2) + Math.pow(labB,2) );

    return [lchL,lchC,lchH];
}

function to_degrees (angle) 
{
    if (angle > 0) 
        {
            angle = (angle / Math.PI ) * 180;
        }
    else
        {
            angle = 360 - ( Math.abs(angle) / Math.PI ) * 180;
        }

  return angle;
}


var myLab = [20, 7, -25]; 
var myLCH = LAB_to_LCH(myLab); // 20, 25.95, 272.2
// should be // 20, 25.95, 285.64

var myLab = [91, -42, 57]; 
var myLCH = LAB_to_LCH(myLab); // 91.0 , 70.80254, 88.9949
// should be // 91.00, 70.80 126.38

It works. (Well... two outta three ain't bad!) The Hue values are out considerably when checking what they should be on colourmine.org
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Your code is fine - but there is a tiny typo -
var lchH = Math.atan( labB, labA );

needs to be
var lchH = Math.atan2( labB, labA );

Arctan got a sequel - who knew?!
